# How common set up and clear down jobs are performed in py.test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Python's [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) has a handy way to perform common set up and clear down jobs by grouping the relevant functions into a class that inherits `unittest.TestCase` and providing `setUp` and `tearDown` functions for that class. However, I couldn't find similar mechanism in [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have already found the answer: it's called "Test fixture management: and is discussed here: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2005/01/python-unit-testing-part-3-pytest-tool.html